# NodeJs + TS does not recognize any route

Tags: node.js, typescript

Description of the problem:
I am developing my Nodejs backend with Typescript Mongo and Express, I implemented the
and I declare the routes and they don't work apparently the router is not working

```
 routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
    controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {
      this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
    });
    };
```

I put log in the method that declares the routes and if it enters, I also put logs in the for and this also enters.

```
controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {
  console.log('inside');
  this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
 });
```

I also tried putting manually my route and it worked:

```
routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
this.app.use('/api/',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('inside');
});    
};
```

my interface IController:

```
export interface IController{
  path:string;
  router:Router;
  initRoutes():void;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by specifying again that it is a Router type of express and at this moment all the routes worked:

```
routes = (controllers: IController[]) => {  
  
    controllers.forEach((controller: IController) => {    
      const routeTemp :Router = controller.router;
      this.app.use('/api/', controller.router);
    });
  };
```